# Has SDL2.0 SetRenderDrawColor and TTF_RenderUNICODE_Blended memory issues?

Tags: c++, memory, sdl, sdl-2

I have a work-related C/C++ SDL 2.0 project - originally developed and compiled on Win7 computer for x86 platform (With MS Visual Studio) that was working fine for the whole time. Since the program was meant to run also at newer Win10 x64 devices, I moved the entire solution to a newer Win10 x64 computer, changed all SDL2 libraries, header files etc. for the x64 version and rebuilt the solution for x64 architecture.

The program is basically an advanced diagnostic screen with dials, icons and text information, so it uses variety of colors, fonts, geometry etc.

After the recompilation for x64 platform, I noticed that the colors of some elements are absolutely off. For example - a rectangle that should be grey (used SDL_SetRenderDrawColor one step before drawing the rect.) is suddenly green, despite its given grey RGB numbers as input arguments. Even the function SDL_GetRenderDrawColor called before and/or after drawing of the rectangle returns values 195, 195, 195, but the rectangle is shown green.

Rectangle drawing function:

```
void DrawRectangle(SDL_Color color, int pozX, int pozY, int width, int height)
{
    SDL_Rect Proportions = { pozX, pozY, width, height };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, color.r, color.g, color.b, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &Proportions);
}
```

Rectangle drawing call:

```
DrawRectangle(grey, pocpozX, 182, width, height);
```

Later I have noticed that this rectangle inherits its color from a text rendered a few steps earlier. If I change the color of this text, it for some strange reason applies also for the rectangle.

Text drawing function:

```
void DrawText(std::wstring text, TTF_Font *font, int pozX, int pozY, SDL_Color color)
{
    typedef std::basic_string<Uint16, std::char_traits<Uint16>, std::allocator<Uint16> > u16string;
    std::wstring text_sf_str = text;
    u16string utext_sf_str(text_sf_str.begin(), text_sf_str.end());
    SDL_Surface* text_sf = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Blended(font, utext_sf_str.c_str(), color);
    SDL_Texture* text_Tx = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, text_sf);
    int text_TxW;
    int text_TxH;
    SDL_QueryTexture(text_Tx, NULL, NULL, &text_TxW, &text_TxH);
    SDL_Rect textrect = { pozX, pozY, text_TxW, text_TxH };
    SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, text_Tx, NULL, &textrect);
    SDL_FreeSurface(text_sf);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(text_Tx);
}
```

Notice all these conversions needed to display a wstring text with some uncommonly used UNICODE characters. I don't quite understand why SDL needs to be passed each character as Uint16 number, this could have been done better. I also don't understand the need of using SDL_QueryTexture just in order to display the text proportions right. I would expect the user to want to display the text not anyhow stretched by default. This all seems to me unnecessarily complicated.

**Funny thing is, that if I remove SDL_DestroyTexture tag, there is of course a huge memory leak, but the problem disappears.**

Text drawing call - in a for loop, this draws numeric labels onto speedometer axis:

```
if (i % 20 == 0)
        {
            if (i <= 160)
            {
                DrawText(str2, font, posX, posY, grey);
            }
            else
            {
                DrawText(str2, font, posX, posY, green);
            }
        }
```

... And this very "green" as the last argument of the call is what causes the rectangle to be green also - despite the fact that more elements are drawn between this text and rectangle so SDL_SetRenderDrawColor is called multiple times.

I have also noticed that some shown numbers are for a little while glitching some senseless values every n-th second, so I guess this is a memory-related problem. Of course there are more color problems, this was just for an example. Due to company policy, I cannot be more specific or post the full code here.

If I switch back to x86 configuration (with the right libraries of course), the problem now remains the same.

Comment: Conversion from 32-bit to 64-bit is not necessarily as simple as just compiling against new libraries.  There are several classes of traps that can bite you, generally related to making non-portable assumptions about the sizes of things.  It takes considerable discipline to write code that avoids all such assumptions.  I suggest turning on all available compiler warnings, performing a clean recompilation, and fixing *all* warnings.

Comment: Looks like variation of https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4768 , which should be fixed in SDL hg but not in release yet. You can upgrade to upstream version, downgrade to previous SDL release, or use different renderer implementation (e.g. opengl).

Comment: It was indeed a SDL-related bug. Upgrading to SDL 2.0.10 is what caused the problem, not the conversion to x64 platform itself. After downgrading to SDL 2.0.8 everything works fine again - on both x86 and x64 architectures.